# How can i access entity manager if i create custom event in symfony2

Tags: php, events, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have created custom event like when user is generataed then Event dispatcher will fire that event.

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.iamproblematic.com/leveraging-the-symfony2-event-dispatcher/). I want to know that in his `class CommentListener` how can I access the entity manager because I want to persist few things in the database.

The class is like this:

```
class CommentListener
{
    protected $mailer;

    public function __construct(Swift_Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    public function onCommentEvent(CommentEvent $event)
    {
        $post = $event->getPost();
        $comment = $event->getComment();

        foreach ($post->getSubscribers() as $subscriber) {
            $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject('New comment posted on ' . $post->getTitle())
                ->setFrom('send@example.com')
                ->setTo($subscriber->getEmail())
                ->setBody("Hey, somebody left a new comment on a post you're subscribed to! It says: " . $comment->getBody())
            ;
            $this->mailer->send($message);
        }
    }
}
```

So how can I access entity manager inside `onCommentEvent`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Listeners are normal services. You can just inject it into constructor along with `mailer`. Something along these lines:

Service:

```
services:
    foo_bundle.listener.comment:
        class: FooVendorBarBundleEventListenerCommentListener
        arguments:
            mailer: "@mailer"
            entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: foo_bundle.post.comment_added, method: onCommentEvent }
```

Listener class:

```
class CommentListener
{
    protected $mailer;

    protected $entityManager;

    public function __construct(Swift_Mailer $mailer, $entityManager)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

...
```

If you ever need to find out name of certain service run `php app/console container:debug`.

Comment: i am using default doctrine entity manager. what will i write there

Comment: I updated the answer. Default doctrine's entity manager is `@doctrine.orm.entity_manager` (which is alias for `@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager`.