# How can an object subscribe to an event?

Tags: php, symfony, mediator

I have a subscriber which implements the [EventSubscriberInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventSubscriberInterface.html). However, in the [Event dispatcher component documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html), it is said that to subscribe to an event, I should call `$dispatcher->addSubscriber()`.

Now, for my example, imagine you have a `Mailer` class which subscribes to some events and sends e-mails. My basic question is, where can I add this to the application so that this object will be added as a listener application-wide? In other terms, where should I call `$dispatcher->addSubscriber()` that is bound to run before the event happens?

Comment: use 'tag' attribute in your config like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771368/how-can-i-access-entity-manager-if-i-create-custom-event-in-symfony2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am repeating myself over and over again:

Dev's rule number 1 (one) : **Man pages are the programmer's best friend**

Everything you need to know is right here in [Symfony Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html), the section you are interested in follows:

**Configuring the Listener/Subscriber**

Now that the class is created, you just need to register it as a service and notify Symfony that it is a "listener" on the kernel.exception event by using a special "tag":
YAML

```
# app/config/config.yml
services:
    kernel.listener.your_listener_name:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\AcmeExceptionListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException }
```

Comment: If I am understanding your answer and the documentation page both correctly, this is only for Doctrin, and not custom events that have nothing to do with a database. My question is about these types of events, not events that happen because of an interaction with the database.

Comment: events are part of the DI Container... doesn't matter where the event is fired, to setup the listener/subscriber you use `tag` attribute when injecting the listening class

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to reflect this more clearly for those who find my question later on? Perhaps use the link below because it is more general and isn't just based on Doctrin. Thanks a lot. The link is http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html

Comment: done. Although users should know that the service container is not only for Doctrine